# useState in import

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, import, react-props

I get an error when I use useState in my `App.js` saying **"Cannot use useState at a top level"**.

I created a component in src folder called `Box.js` containing an array with 6 objects each with two properties;

```
- id 
- On(with boolean values)
```

Then I imported the component in my `App.js` which is being rendered through `index.js`. I imported useState

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState(Box);

const boxElements = boxes.map((box) => {
  <div className="box" key={box.id}></div>
});
```

My expectation was to pass the data from the Box.js to App.js as state but I received an error.

Comment: Please provide code where the issue occurs. Use the editor.

Comment: import Header from './Components/Header';
import './App.css';
import Form from './Components/Form';
import React from 'react';
import Box from './Box';
import Memes from './Components/Memes';
import Count from './Components/Count';

const [squares, setSquares] = React.useState(Box);
const squareElements = squares.map((square) => {
  <div className="box" key={square.id}>{ }</div>
})

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      
      <Form />
      {/* <Memes/> */}
      <Count />
     {squareElements}
    </>
  )
}

export default App;

Answer (score 0):

React hooks can only be used inside components. As for the code you provided, it is not.

Trying the useState hook inside the function App.

Answer (score 0):

I created a file called State.js where I used useState, which was passed as props to the App.js component and it worked. The trick is ensuring that components using useState to pass as props, is close to each other.